# Finding a function for othorgonality

Tags: linear-algebra

**Let the polynomial $f$ of the form $f : t \rightarrow a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2 $. Find the function $f$ such that $f$ is orthogonal to $t$, $t^2$ and $\|f\| = 1$.**

I got stuck with finding function. 
Here is what I have done so far: 
Since $f$ must be orthogonal to $t$, $t^2$ and $\|f\| = 1$, we have $\langle f,t \rangle =0$, $\langle f,t^2 \rangle = 0$  and $\langle f, f \rangle = 1 $ that satisfy $\|f\|=1$.

Then I need to find $f(t) = a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2$ s.t 
\begin{align}
 \int _0 ^1 (a_0+a_1 t + a_2 t^2)t\, dt = 0 ... \tag{eq(1)}\\
 \int _0 ^1 (a_0+a_1 t + a_2 t^2)t^, dt=0 ... \tag{eq(2)}\\
\int _0 ^1 (a_0+a_1 t + a_2 t^2)^2\, dt =1 ...\tag{ eq(3)}
\end{align}

When I integrate the first equation, I get $$ {a_0\over 2}  + {a_1\over3} + {a_2 \over4}  = 0 $$

When I integrate the first equation, I get $$ {a_0\over 3}  + {a_1\over4} + {a_2 \over5}  = 0 $$

When I integrate the third equation, I get $$ {a_2^2 \over 7} + {a_1 a_2 \over 3} + {a_1^2a_0a_2\over 5} + {a_0 a_1\over 2} + {a_0 ^2\over 3} = 1$$

I don't know how to continue so please help me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't get what you say you did since you **should have gotten** numbers. For example:

$$\int_0^1(a_0t+a_1t^2+a_2t^3)dt=\left.\left(\frac{a_0}2t^2+\frac{a_1}3t^3+\frac{a_2}4t^4\right)\right|_0^1=\frac{a_0}2+\frac{a_1}3+\frac{a_2}4=0$$

and etc.

You get several linear equations. Solve the system now.

Comment: So I have to take coefficients from all the equation and solve?

Comment: You have to solve Riemann integrals. In this case, as function of those coefficients $\;a_i\;$. BTW, the third integral's expression is wrong.

Comment: I am still lost. Would you give me some more hints?

Comment: @user179313, have you already studied Riemann integration? Because this linear algebra question requires that. Just look what I did with the first integral.

Comment: Yeah, I edited my integrals and so I guess I need to find the values of those coefficients to get a function. Am I right? Thanks!